# How do I calculate the latest time to start the third Shabbos meal on erev Yom Tov?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, zemanim, meal-seudah

From [myzemanim.com](http://www.myzmanim.com/day.aspx?vars=39090887/5-26-2012/elab///////////////c7178c) for where I live, for this Shabbos, erev Shovuos, the “sho’o zemanis” (Proportional Hour)  Gra & Baal Tanya is 1hr:22mins. 
Nightfall - 3 Stars is around 10:30 pm.
Shkia is around 9:20 pm.

How do I calculate the latest time to start Sholosh seudas “sho’o asiris”?

Are there any leniencies bearing in mind the length of the sho’o zemanis?

Comment: 3 * 82 min = 246 min = 4 hr 6 min. 9:20 - 4 hr 6 min = 5:14

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Are there any leniencies bearing in mind the length of the sho’o zemanis?"

Comment: Three clock hours = 3 hours. Three sho’os zemaniyos = 4 clock hours approx. 

(1) Do we really need to wait 4 clock hours? 

(2) We can't eat until after nightfall (and maariv). This is (at least) another 70 minutes later.

Comment: I don't see how either of those will lead to a kula in terms of seudah shelishit. But you should CYLOR regarding if you can say maariv and/or kiddush before tzeit as there are some kulas to be found in that area.

Answer (score 2):

The start of *shaa asiris* is nine twelfths (or, more simply, three fourths) of the way from sunrise to sunset. Subtract sunrise from sunset (so if sunrise is 7:41 and sunset is 18:12, you get 18:12−7:41=10:31), divide by four (10:31/4=2:37:45), and subtract that length of time from sunset (18:12−2:37:45=15:34:15).

That said, this is a math-oriented answer, not so much an halachic one. I can't speak to your subquestion, "Are there any leniencies bearing in mind the length of the sho’o zemanis?".

Comment: Why didn't you use the numbers in his example?

Comment: @DoubleAA he gave no sunrise time in his example.

Comment: The link gives it all for his location (4:52 AM). And secondly you could backcalculate it from the sha'ah zemanit that he gave.

Comment: @DoubleAA, re "calculate it from the sha'ah zemanit that he gave", true. But people usually know sunrise and sunset, not the length of a _shaa z'manis_. I think my answer is more generally useful than if I'd started with information on when sunset is and how long a _shaa z'manis_ is. Re "The link gives it all for his location", yes, but I was too lazy to check the link. And my answer is a good general one. A specific one for his situation would border on _p'sak_, which I'm loath to do.

Comment: As you said 'this is a math-oriented answer' so I would think a PhD in mathematics is more suited to give the correct result than an accomplished lamdan who can't solve a quadratic equation.

Comment: @DoubleAA PhDs in math are notorious for their poor basic-arithmetic skills. `:-)`

Comment: Indeed they are :) Do you mind at least [double checking mine](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16586/how-do-i-calculate-the-latest-time-to-start-the-third-shabbos-meal-on-erev-yom-t/16588#comment35734_16586)?

Comment: @DoubleAA 5:13 not 5:14. (Rounding error.)

Comment: As they say 'Do not rely on zmanim times to the last moment'