# How does one have Seudah Shlishit when Erev Yom Tov occurs on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, yom-tov, meal-seudah

[This site](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:V0PjfJ-Las8J:https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/wed_10_16_13/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) says:

> one may not eat a meal on the eve of a Festival starting from the time
>   of the afternoon prayers, just like on Fridays before Shabbos.

Does this mean that when Erev Yom Tov occurs on Shabbat, as it does this year for Shavuot, one may not have Se'udah Shlishit in shul after a "late" mincha (around the Friday candle lighting time?) Or, is there an exception made for *Seudah Shlishit*?

If not, what is the recommended method of when to have *Seudah Shlishit*?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16586/759

Answer (score 5):

*Magen Avraham* ([OC 529:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2889)) writes that ideally one should eat *Seudah Shlishit* before *Mincha Ketanah* (9½ [halachic hours](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/526872/jewish/Hours.htm) after sunrise), but if he forgot to eat before, he may eat the meal even after *Mincha Ketanah*.

Answer (score 0):

As with any Yom Tov that occurs after Shabbat, the prevalent custom is to wash by lunch. Have a brief meal with just fish. Daven early mincha if possible and then wash again for third meal. At least that’s what we do

Comment: Sources would really increase the quality of this answer. To forestall future questions: "Prevalent by whom ?"