# Zemirot during Third Meal on Shabbat Rosh Hashana

Tags: shabbat, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shabbat-songs

Should Zemirot (chants) be said at all Shabbat meals that fall on Rosh Hashanah?

Does what is said about Rosh Hashanah: "One does not say poetry on Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur" (Rosh Hashanah 32b) also apply to chanting?

Comment: "_Does what is said about Rosh Hashanah: 'One does not say poetry on Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur' (Rosh Hashanah 32b) also apply to chanting?_" Do you mean "[מפני מה אין ישראל אומרים שירה **לפניך** בראש השנה וביום הכפורים?](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rosh_Hashanah.32b.22?lang=bi&lang2=en)"? If so: Why might it apply to anything more than Hallel [not] being said during the prayer service ("מכלל דבראש השנה ליכא **הלל**")?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one have Seudah Shlishit when Erev Yom Tov occurs on Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91939/how-does-one-have-seudah-shlishit-when-erev-yom-tov-occurs-on-shabbat)